# Why can Genya eat demons?

Tags: demon-slayer

In the manga it's shown that Genya can eat demons and,

> gain their powers, like regeneration

Why can Genya can eat demons? Is this ever explained?

Comment: At the moment (10-10-2019) there is not explication in the manga, he just can. Like some other powers in the blood on others pjs.

Answer (score 1):

According to the source manga, Genya has a special ability that allows him to eat demons. He has immense bite strength and a special digestive organs which allows him to tear through the demons. This ability allows him to overcome his other shortcomings such as the inability to perform the breathing styles. [Some speculate that it is a result of an experimental procedure that Genya underwent in the Final Selection](https://www.sportskeeda.com/anime/is-genya-demon-demon-slayer-explained). Also by consuming demons, Genya can mimic the appearance as well as some of the powers of that specific demons.

Source: https://www.radiotimes.com/tv/fantasy/anime/demon-slayer-genya-explained/